# Docker container not running properly

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am working in a base Docker container for Symfony development. I am using Docker Toolset for Windows. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM        centos:6.7
MAINTAINER  Reynier Perez <reynierpm@gmail.com>

# basic env fix
ENV             TERM xterm

# Install REMI and EPEL repos
RUN     yum update -y
RUN     yum install -y mc wget yum-utils htop nano curl git
RUN     wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm \
        && wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm \
        && rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm

RUN     yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
RUN     yum install -y  php \
                        php-common \
                        php-cli \
                        php-gd \
                        php-intl \
                        php-mbstring \
                        php-mcrypt \
                        php-opcache \
                        php-pdo \
                        php-pear \
                        php-pecl-apcu \
                        php-imagick \
                        php-pecl-xdebug \
                        php-xml \
                        php-mysqlnd \
                        php-soap \
                        php-pdo-dblib

RUN         curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN         curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony && chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony

# Configure Services
# Create a copy of default files and remove them
# Apache
RUN         cp /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.default
RUN         rm -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
ADD         httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/
# Add default VirtualHost
ADD         vhost.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/
#PHP
RUN         cp /etc/php.ini /etc/php.ini.default
RUN         rm -f /etc/php.ini
ADD         php.ini /etc/
# Add PHP info default script
ADD         info.php /var/www/html
# Setup permissions
RUN         chown -R apache:root /var/www/html && \
            find /var/www/html -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 2775 && \
            find /var/www/html -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0664

# Mount Volumes
VOLUME      /var/www/html
WORKDIR     /var/www/html

EXPOSE      80

CMD         service httpd restart
```

When I build the machine using:

```
docker build --tag=symfony-dev .
```

I got this message:

```
Successfully built c7bc46e1f84c 
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a
Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files
and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x'
permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions
for sensitive files and directories.
```

The next step is to run the container using:

```
docker run symfony-dev
```

Then I try to see the info for that container:

```
docker inspect symfony-dev
```

And I got a JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:c7bc46e1f84c6d1a543c515d134184486dcb0e3e81c81f269ff1bb10791a3c9e",
        "RepoTags": [
            "symfony-dev:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:db8021c4307e547ae7fee4afd3b964e72fde6422dbb8a5292b4bf441beb7d0b4",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2016-04-02T02:16:45.891399606Z",
        "Container": "e02be1ee3e12ef79bff0c0bbb7b7751f7368d5c06872df37a58439d21d69d57f",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "72ba20be3774",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "TERM=xterm"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) CMD [\"/bin/sh\" \"-c\" \"service httpd restart\"]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:db8021c4307e547ae7fee4afd3b964e72fde6422dbb8a5292b4bf441beb7d0b4",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/www/html": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {
                "License": "GPLv2",
                "Vendor": "CentOS"
            }
        },
        "DockerVersion": "1.10.3",
        "Author": "Reynier Perez \u003creynierpm@gmail.com\u003e",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "72ba20be3774",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "TERM=xterm"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "service httpd restart"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:db8021c4307e547ae7fee4afd3b964e72fde6422dbb8a5292b4bf441beb7d0b4",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/www/html": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {
                "License": "GPLv2",
                "Vendor": "CentOS"
            }
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 756378663,
        "VirtualSize": 756378663,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        }
    }
]
```

But where is the IP address? How I reach the Apache on that container? If I run the command ps as follow:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I didn't see any container running, why? I am missing something here?

**UPDATE**

Following @cricket_007 suggestion I have added the `httpd_foreground` as in official Dockerfile for Apache and now I saw the container running if I run `docker ps` but I am still having a few issues:

- If I run the container to get into bash as `docker run -it --name=symfony symfony-dev bash` I got this error: `new state of nil is invalid` which I don't know how to fix.
- In the other side I am seeing 172.17.0.2 as IP address but I am not able to reach it as Apache meaning `http://172.17.0.2/info.php` I have a few suspicious regarding firewalld and/or SELinux but I am not sure

Can I have some advice on this two issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container is dying after it starts because your command  `service httpd restart` doesn't keep open any foreground process.

You could `tail -f` the Apache log file, for example as a CMD and use RUN for restarting the server like you currently are.

Comment: You mean add `RUN tailf /etc/http/logs/XXXXXX.log` ?

Comment: Not as a RUN, no. As the CMD

Comment: Actually the official Apache image uses `exec httpd -DFOREGROUND`, here is the script used in CMD https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/bc72e42914f671e725d85a01ff037ce87c827f46/2.4/httpd-foreground

Comment: @warmoverflow Thanks for the link. I didn't want to go search for it. I had the right idea, though, there needs to be a foreground process

Comment: @cricket_007 can you take a look to the UPDATE on OP?

Comment: If you have new questions, please make new posts. I can tell you the second problem happens because you didn't map the port 80 from the container to your computer. The first problem is that by invoking bash when you run the container, you are overriding the CMD function. You have to first run the container and then `docker exec -it` on it to get to a shell